# A biography that's out of this world

Tags: riddle, cryptic-clues

Who or what was I?

> Initially, woeful interviews and a bad video mix-up gave me my name. 
>  Then, I was a terrible druggy sat with zits and known for my confusing mantras. 
>  Following that, I hunted the kiwi erratically from one stop to the next. 
>  After hitting bottom and contemplating my eulogy, I found my place as one in four in a device made by fifty. 
>  I turned to a middle-class spiritual leader to complete my unusual recovery. 
>  At the end, I looked towards tomorrow and people loved my finale when I made crabs talk weirdly.

In your answer, please give a clear explanation of each line.

Comment: bad video mix-up -> anagram of "bad video"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer is

> DAVID BOWIE

Initially, woeful interviews =

> WI

bad video mixup

> BAD VIDEO + WI = Anagram of David Bowie

terrible druggy sat + zits

> Anagram of Ziggy Stardust

confusing mantras

> anagram of Starman

Hunted the Kiwi erratically (thanks to ChrisCudmore)

> anagram of thin white duke

one stop to the next

> Station to Station

Hitting bottom

> Not sure, but could be Low

contemplating my eulogy

> Ashes to ashes (dust to dust)

one in four in a device made by fifty

> Tin Machine - Tin is element # 50

middle-class spiritual leader (also thanks to ChrisCudmore)

> The Buddha of Suburbia

At the end, I looked towards tomorrow

> The Next Day, his penultimate album

people loved my finale when I made crabs talk weirdly

> anagram of Blackstar, his last album

Comment: Hunted the Kiwi erratically -> Thin White Duke

Comment: @ChrisCudmore yeah...thanks...there's lots of those in there...i'll keep editing as i find them

Comment: Nice job. I'd have never gotten it.

Comment: Middle class spiritual leader could be "The Buddha of Suburbia", a film soundtrack

Comment: @ChrisCudmore yup...good one

Comment: I think the only unsolved clues left are "contemplating my eulogy" and "complete my unusual recovery"

Comment: Fantastic work! You can ignore the "complete my unusual recovery" bit, that was me fudging a little to fit the style of the puzzle narrative while hinting at "alternative music". The  "contemplating my eulogy" part was intended to be one of the more straight forward bits but I think I've been misleading. Think instead, "words said at a funeral".

Comment: @hexomino ashes to ashes, dust to dust...right?

Comment: @Munir Perfect.